# Associative array corresponding to column name in a table

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, api, server

```
<?php

  header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
  header('Content-Type: application/json');

  include_once '../../config/Database.php';
  include_once '../../models/Post.php';

  $database = new Database();
  $db = $database->connect();


  $post = new Post($db);

  $result = $post->read();

  $num = $result->rowCount();

  if ($num > 0) {
       $posts_arr = array();
       $posts_arr['data'] = array();

       while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
           extract($row);

           $post_item = array(
             'id' => $id,
             'title' => $title,
             'body'  => html_entity_decode($body),
             'author' => $author,
             'category_id' => $category_id,
             'category_name' => $category_name  
           );

           array_push($posts_arr['data'], $post_item);

           echo json_encode($posts_arr);

       } 

  } else {
      echo json_encode(
          array('message' => 'No Posts Found')

      );

  }
```

My problem :

I try to change **$title** to **$the_title**, it generates error, but when I change the column name in the table to '**the_title**', it works! 
My confusion is that since anything start with '$' sign is a variable, and it can be any name actually, but in this particular situation, why the name of the variable needs to be same as the name of the table's column.

```
 $post_item = array(
             'id' => $id,
             'title' => $title,
             'body'  => html_entity_decode($body),
             'author' => $author,
             'category_id' => $category_id,
             'category_name' => $category_name  
           );
```

Comment: Don't use `extract($row);`, you can easily access the values using `$row['id']`.  `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` returns an associative array with the column names as the keys and the value as the ... er.... value.  So the key name must match the name of the column.

Comment: speaking of key, I can change the key name to anything, it still works, e.g : `'title_anything'  => $title`

Comment: The key in `$post_item` is entirely up to you (as long as it fits in PHP rules).

Comment: @Nigel Ren From what I read, It has to do with `extract($row)` which converts the array keys into variable names and the array values into variable value. I got lost at the beginning, I thought It has nothing to do with `extract($row)`, that's why I treat it as common variable rules.